# KStreams outerjoin acting like innerjoin

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, outer-join

I am using `.outerJoin` to join two streams together. The expected behaviour is that I would get a record in the output for all records in both inputs; but actually I'm only getting an output where there is a record with the same key in both inputs - which directly contradicts the documentation.

Code as follows:

```java
KStream<String, String> originalStream = builder.stream("original-topic");
KStream<String, String> augmentedStream = builder.stream("augmented-topic");

KStream<String, String> mergedStream = originalStream.outerJoin(augmentedStream, (value1,value2)->
{
    if (value2 == null) // no augmented message
    {
        System.out.println("No Augmented message for original message " + value1);
        return value1;
    }
    else if(value1 == null) // no raw message
    {
        System.out.println("No original message for Augmented message " + value2);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("pair found: " + value1 + "," + value2);
    }
    
    return value2;  
}
// Add a time-based join window
,JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceWithNoGrace(Duration.ofSeconds(1)));
```

Test Data (note that 13 is not present in the augmented data, and 19 not present in the original):

```java
// populate some test data
try(Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(config, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer()))
{
    Arrays.asList("11,a","12,c","13,e","14,g","15,i","16,k","17,m").forEach(s->producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("original-topic",s.split(",")[0],s.split(",")[1])));
             
   Arrays.asList("11,ta","12,tc","12,td","14,tg","15,ti","16,tk","17,tm","19,to").forEach(s->producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("augmented-topic",s.split(",")[0],s.split(",")[1])));
    producer.flush();
}
```

Output:

```
pair found: a,ta
pair found: c,tc
pair found: c,td
pair found: g,tg
pair found: i,ti
pair found: k,tk
pair found: m,tm
```

As you can see, I would expect a printed output for 13 (`e`) and 19 (`to`), saying they're not in the augmented and raw streams respectively; but there's nothing there - and breakpoints confirm that the code doesn't get called for 13 and 19, even though an outer join should be doing so with null for the other value. I get that it will wait until after the join window to do so; but given that I've set it to 1 second, it shouldn't take long.

What I am missing here?

---

Update - if I add a delay between writes (and move the single items to the front of the arrays), then this works (but of course doesn't find any pairs, only unpaired items, because 1100 is longer than the window period):

```java
Arrays.asList("13,e","11,a","12,c","14,g","15,i","16,k","17,m").forEach(s->
{
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("original-topic",s.split(",")[0],s.split(",")[1]));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(900);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
Arrays.asList("19,to","11,ta","12,tc","12,td","14,tg","15,ti","16,tk","17,tm","17,tm").forEach(s->
{
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("augmented-topic",s.split(",")[0],s.split(",")[1]));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

```
No Augmented message for original message e
No Augmented message for original message a
No Augmented message for original message c
No Augmented message for original message g
No Augmented message for original message i
No Augmented message for original message k
No Augmented message for original message m
No original message for Augmented message to
No original message for Augmented message ta
No original message for Augmented message tc
No original message for Augmented message td
No original message for Augmented message tg
No original message for Augmented message ti
No original message for Augmented message tk
```

If I extend the window to 10 seconds, it then finds the pairs again; and this time it finds `e` as an unpaired item too; but not `to`.

```
pair found: a,ta
pair found: c,tc
pair found: c,td
pair found: g,tg
No Augmented TD message for original message e
pair found: i,ti
pair found: k,tk
pair found: m,tm
pair found: m,tm
```

So, to me, it looks like there's something preventing it finding unpaired items for a join if there's only a small stream of messages?